# native JavaScript - remove html tag but leave contents in same place

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Some sample html:

```html
<section>
   <span class="unnecessary">
      this is content before a <a href="#">link</a> and after it.  I really don't need span.unnecessary and and to remove it
   </span>
</section>
```

Is there a way in vanilla JavaScript to simply remove the `<span class="unnecessary">` using DOM methods?

Comment: Is that span the only child of the section? Do you really need to remove it or can you just remove the className? It would help if you gave more detail about the higher level problem you are trying to solve

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select by class only

```js
var unnecessaries = document.getElementsByClassName('unnecessary')

//start LOOP for each unnecessary element
    unnecessaries[0].outerHTML = unnecessaries[0].innerHTML
//end LOOP
```

if you want to select by combination of span and class

```js
var unnecessaries = document.querySelectorAll('span.unnecessary')

//start LOOP for each unnecessary element
    unnecessaries[0].outerHTML = unnecessaries[0].innerHTML
//end LOOP
```

Comment: add .trim() after innerHTML in case it's returning with extra white space.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
  var b = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

  while(b.length) {
  var parent = b[ 0 ].parentNode;
  while( b[ 0 ].firstChild ) {
    parent.insertBefore(  b[ 0 ].firstChild, b[ 0 ] );
  }
   parent.removeChild( b[ 0 ] );
  }
```

The resulting html

```
   <section>this is content before a <a href="#">link</a> and after it.  I really 
   don't 
  need span.unnecessary and and to remove it

  </section>
```